# Windows Batch file debugger?

Tags: debugging, command-line, batch-file

Is there a program like Visual Studio that allows you to debug (dos) batch files?  What techniques could I use to debug?  Martin Brown answered a batch file question with a nice for / each loop.  I would love to see the values of the variables as they loop.

`for /R A %i IN (*.jpg) DO xcopy %i B /M`

Comment: if you need to debug a batch file potentially you are using the wrong tool for the task. Why not try cscript.exe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print the values of the variables as they loop you could try:

```
for /l %A in (1,1,10) do (
    @echo %A
)
```

If you want to stop and examine each line as it is executed try:

```
for /l %A in (1,1,10) do (
    @echo %A
    pause
)
```

which will halt the script at each iteration.

Your example looks like a backup script for images;

```
for /R %i in (*.jpg) do (
    @echo %i
    xcopy %i %DESTINATION% /M
)
```

If you make a script of this you can pipe all the output to a log file, just don't forget to use %%i instead of %i if you're not typing this at the shell.

Comment: Nice.  I did not know you could use parentheses around the do in the for.  Now the "echo this" statements make sense for the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

you mean besides just doing an echo HERE I AM type of thing? i don't know of any. i just debug my batch files by remming out the actions and adding echo's until i know its working correctly. i also wrote my own one line "outputdebugstring" application that sends anything on its command line to the debugger, but that probably isn't necessary for most batches where you can just watch the screen. inserting "pause"'s can help slow things down too.

best regards
don

Comment: Also removing echo off is usually a great help in determining where exactly an error occurs.

Comment: I like the "echo this" statements.  Since there are multiple streams, can you set a variable for debug then direct these separate from the normal output?  Something like 2>&1?

Answer (score 2):

Well i found one it name is **[Running Steps](http://www.steppingsoftware.com/ssportal/Downloads/tabid/58/Default.aspx)**. You can read more about it at its [Homepage](http://www.steppingsoftware.com/ssportal/) . Anyway it supports breakpoints, step in step over and stuff like that :)

Comment: The link is dead, it's a AD. website. :(

Comment: both links are broken!

Answer (score 2):

**Running Steps** is like the IDE.  You get an 'Analyzer' which is the equivalent of a compiler.  It shows you errors and warnings in your code.  It has an integrated environment that allows you to step over, into, etc.  It even unrolls for loops which I find awesome.  Check it out at http://www.steppingsoftware.com.   It's helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Like VS ? Not that I know of.

As far as variable values go, you can always print them out.

Answer (score 1):

I use Notepad++ to at least give me colour coding when I'm writing/modifying.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other users you can use **Running Steps** software.
You can download it from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120421211043/http://www.steppingsoftware.com/ssportal/Downloads/tabid/58/Default.aspx)

Comment: It seems only to work on x86 (32-bit) machines, it's a 30 days trial version only. The developer (https://stackoverflow.com/users/756697/gonzalo-isaza) does not seem to maintain the software or provide licenses any more.